# Retrieve data from database using hyperlink control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello everyone as I am new in asp.net C# I need some help from seniors

There is a table with following columns:

```
ID int unique not null
Title varchar(250) not null
Username varchar(100) not null
Datetime datetime not null
Shortviews varchar(500) not null
Fullviews varchar(1000) not null
Photo image not null
```

I have successfully coded the page for inserting data in this table Now I want to display it on the page, I used repeater data control to display its Title only and put it in attribute the code is below

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="article_rep" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="article_rep_ItemCommand">
        <itemtemplate>
            <ul class="list1">
                <li><a href="#"><%# Eval("Title")%></a></li>
            </ul>
        </itemtemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Behind the code I selected Data with following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LgnConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string str;
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    con.Open();
    str = "select top 5 Title from table ORDER BY Datetime DESC";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    world_rep.DataSource = reader;
    world_rep.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

it display the table records for last five rows, I want that when I click on any title it display the rest of columns information associated with that Title, which I clicked, on another page that will be Details.aspx

I know it is simple and easy for seniors but I get struck on it please help me, thanks in advance. What I will have to code on Details.aspx and what will I have to code on Details.aspx.cs

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Sir question is: what will be the procedure to fetch all records on details.aspx page when i click on Title link. It is just like news when we click on a news in news website it opens a new page with having detail information of that news, we clicked earlier

Comment: Ok, but what problem are you having? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

```
//Define the class to hold the Tite property  values.
public class RepeaterTitle
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
}



  string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LgnConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string str;
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    con.Open();
    str = "select top 5 Title from table ORDER BY Datetime DESC";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    List<RepeaterTitle> TitleLIst = new List<RepeaterTitle>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        RepeaterTitle oTitle = new RepeaterTitle();
        oTitle.Title = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        TitleLIst.Add(oTitle);
    }
    article_rep.DataSource = TitleLIst;
    article_rep.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component id is wrong in .cs file. Change **world_rep** to **article_rep**. Other things looks good

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LgnConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string str;
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    con.Open();
    str = "select top 5 Title from table ORDER BY Datetime DESC";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    //world_rep.DataSource = reader;
    //world_rep.DataBind();
    article_rep.DataSource = reader;
    article_rep.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

if you need detail page, add a link like this;

```
<asp:Repeater ID="article_rep" runat="server" 
    onitemcommand="article_rep_ItemCommand">
    <itemtemplate>
        <ul class="list1">
            <li><a href="details.asp?id=<%# Eval("ID")%>"><%# Eval("Title")%></a></li>
        </ul>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Create new detail form. Add "Detailsview" component to view file. In the .cs file like this;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LgnConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string str;
    int requestId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]); //Get the ID
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    con.Open();
    str = "select * from table where ID=@ID";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    com.parameters.addWithValue("@ID", requestId); //add ID parameter to query
    SqlDataReader reader;
    reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    myDetailsview.DataSource = reader;
    myDetailsview.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

According to self-organize the Detailsview component

Comment: Sir, thats not the problem i am asking for help how can i display rest of information on another page which is details.aspx, It is just like news when we click on a news in news website it opens a new page with having detail information of that news, i need some help what do i have to code in details.aspx page and what will be behind the code in details.aspx.cs